# How to stop text autocorrection via code

Tags: actionscript-3, autocorrect

I have a translation programme to translate Spanish to English. I am writing code in flash AS3. How to I stop the autocorrection when I am typing on the tablet?
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

According to this artical:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StageText.html#autoCorrect

You can use this function to set the autoCorrect:

`public function set autoCorrect(value:Boolean):void`